# Adding different text in the end of every line in file

Tags: linux, bash

So I am trying to add text to the end of every line in my text file of dates that I currently have.
Example (inside my text file):

```
January 1
January 2
January 3 
february 4 
february 16
februray 17
```

I would like the output to be

```
January 1 2022
January 2 2023
January 3 2024
february 4 2022
february 16 2023
february 17 2024
```

So I would just want to loop those certain years in my list of dates that I have

Comment: `awk '{print $0, (NR-1)%3+2022}'`  or `sed 's/$/ 2022/;n;s/$/ 2023/;n;s/$/ 2024/'` would work on your sample, but you may want to clarify what the rules are to determine what year to append to each line.

Comment: I believe the list of dates would just go in corresponding order of 2022, 2023, 2024 til the end of the file containing the dates, would your solution do that ? So it would be in a repetitive order of 2022, 2023, 2024 then repeats 2022, 2023 , 2024

Comment: Hi I was wondering, so I don't have a first date is it possible for me to skip the first date because when i use lynx and grab the dates from a website there is no date for that column, then continue with 2022.
i.e Skip the first line